# USB Wifi Adapter Not Autoloading

Tags: wireless, usb, 16.04

I have been unplugging and replugging my USB wifi adapter after every boot to get it to recognize.

I can also do this:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8812au
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

But only once I have already unplugged and replugged at least once.

It would be really nice if I could just have it load up automatically as it should on boot.  Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo 8812au  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the performance is improved.

Comment: Yes, that worked.  I noticed though, that the rebooting hesitation started again after issuing the command.  I unplugged the usb dongle and it immediately rebooted.  I plugged it back in, started up, and my internet came on automatically.

Comment: I then did a follow up restart, it restarted immediately with no hesitation and once again, my internet came up on its own.   Can you tell me why this command fixed the problem?  Please explain what we did by executing those commands.

Comment: The command adds the driver to the list of modules that are to be loaded *automatically*, no matter what else the system is doing. It is often, but not always, helpful in these cases. I'm glad it's working.